# 'onShow' event needed in Electron browser window

Tags: javascript, events, electron, show

In Electron I want to trigger a javascript function in a browser window when that browser window is shown.

The code I have at the moment is as follows:

*main.js (Main Process)*

```
myWin = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1200, height: 400, show: false })

.... some time later and under certain circumstances ;-) ....

myWin.show()
```

*usbUpload.js (Browser Window)*

```
function validateFlights() {
   ...blar...
}

this.addEventListener('onshow', () => {
    validateFlights()
})
```

`ValidateFlights()` is the function  in the browser window that I want to execute when the browser window is shown.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call javascript in the renderer process from main process using [`executeJavaScript`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback). Combined with [`'show'`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-show) event of `BrowserWindow` you can do the following:

```js
myWin.on('show', () => {
  myWin.webContents.executeJavaScript('validateFlights()')
})
```

---

Example:

*main.js*

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
  win.once('show', () => {
    win.webContents.executeJavaScript('validateFlights()')
  })
  win.loadURL(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'))
  win.show()
})
```

*index.html*

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function validateFlights() {
        console.log('validated')
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems so close! I've tried it, but I get `"Uncaught ReferenceError: validateFlights is not defined"` in the console window. `validateFlights()` doesn't seem to be in the scope of executeJavaScript. If I do a simple `console.log()` that works exactly as needed, but I have to call `validateFlights()`. Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: It also works with `<script type="text/javascript" src="any.js"></script>`. If you still have trouble with it please share your code

Comment: Excellent! Now working. The problem seemed to be I was using the following syntax to access the `usbUpload.js` from the html:

    `<script> require( 'usbUpload.js' ) </script>`

Once I replaced this with your more conventional code as follows, is works aok:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="usbUpload.js"></script>` Do you know whether the 'require' syntax is just wrong!? I'm happy but puzzled! Many Thanks!

Comment: nothing wrong with `require`! you just have to be precise: `require('./usbUpload')` and `validateFlights = function () { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

In your main process you probably want to do something with [win.show()](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winshow) and the [focus event](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#event-focus) if your window is already open in the background. Something like so:

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
win.on('onFocus', () => {
  win.show()
})
```

Comment: I don't quite see how this helps. I'm already calling `myWin.show()` in the main process in response to an event from the system tray. This works fine and the window is displayed. The problem is I need to add an 'onShow' handler in the browser window which responds to the window being shown. I can then call a local function in the browser window.

Comment: I can only go by my interpretation of what you said. Based on the above, you are opening a window, but it is hiding in the background. You want to bring it to the foreground on click of a menu button. Basically, the on focus event means the window is being brought to the foreground for use, and you can work on it then. If you had more code, it might make more sense

Comment: Hi @unseen_damage - I've clarified the question to focus on only what is needed and added some more code as you mentioned. Does that help at all?